# Cannot connect to SQL Server database regardless of connection string

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm having a tough time to connect to a local SQL Server instance within a C# app.  I can connect to external databases on other servers, but I need to be able to use my own local database.

The exception I get is:

> {"Login failed for user 'ASTROAdmin'."}

There isn't really any more info within the exception, so I don't know if the account doesn't exist, if the password is bad, if the database doesn't exist, etc.  The connection string I'm using is:

> connectionString="Server=MIKE-LAPTOP;Initial
>   Catalog=ASTRO_PROD;Integrated Security=False;User
>   ID=ASTROAdmin;Password=password;Persist Security Info=True;Type System
>   Version=SQL Server 2008;Application Name=OpsMgr;"

I've also ran the following on the server:

```
ALTER LOGIN [ASTROAdmin] WITH PASSWORD=N'password'
```

So the password should be fine.

I've been trying different values (such as `.` and `localhost`) for `Server` and also using `Data Source=` instead, but I get the same exception no matter what.  My theory is that there are multiple instances of SQL Server on this machine, like perhaps SQL Server Express.

Also, if I run the SQL Profiler tool, I don't see anything come up as it tries to connect.  No data what-so-ever.

What's the best way to continue to diagnose this problem?  Thanks!

Comment: You have a login but does the login have access to the database (e.g. a user is created)?

Comment: @ShawnMelton - As far as I can tell.  The ASTROAdmin login is mapped to the ASTROAdmin user in ASTRO_PROD.  I've tried deleting and adding in the users several times, but every time I get the same error.

Comment: I've also went through each setting in both the database user and login one by one and compared them to the settings on the production database.  They're *exactly* the same now.  Yet, I still cannot login.  I have no idea if it's even trying to connect to the right database!

Comment: Check the system health session and look for the security rung buffer events. It might shed light on why.

Comment: Thanks!  I have no idea what any of that means.  We have some DBAs who will be in the office tomorrow, I'll talk to them.

Comment: Have you tried to sync up the user - `ALTER USER ASTROAdmin WITH LOGIN = ASTROAdmin;` provided `ASTROAdmin` is a user in the database you are trying to query and `ASTROAdmin` is the login for the CORRECT sql express instance. Also, can you post the exact error along with severity and state.

Comment: When you say "ran the following on the server" can you provide more details about the connection details *that* session used? Also check the SQL Server error log, you should see a state along with the failed login, and that might yield a clue (see [this post](https://sqlblog.org/2020/07/28/troubleshooting-error-18456)).

Comment: *that* session used my NT credentials.  I'll check the error log when I get back into work tomorrow, thanks!

Comment: The SQL Server error log shows more detail - i.e. it will tell you if your password is wrong or (more likely) if you don't have access to your default database

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to SQL Server Management Studio, then attempt a logon to MIKE-LAPTOP with your provided credentials.  Can you connect?  Any errors thrown?  That will eliminate the possibility of password/permissions.

You mentioned that there could be multiple SQL instances.  Depending on configurations, you may need to specify the instance name and/or port number.

Such as:

```
MIKE-LAPTOP\sql2008 
MIKE-LAPTOP\sql2008,1433
```

Comment: Yes, I always use server\instance it usually does the trick even if there is only one instance

Answer (score 0):

Is your SQL instance in Windows Authentication mode? This wouldn't allow SQL Server accounts to login.

In SQL Server Management Studio, right click on the instance > Properties > Security.

Check that "SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode" is selected under "Server Authentication".

Answer (score 0):

Please check the Event Viewer and look at the Application log. Filter on the MSSQL* sources (MSSQLSERVER for the default instance) and Task Category of Logon. They should be under error # 18456 or similar. Here's one I generated on instance with only Windows authentication enabled...

```
Login failed for user 'xxxxx'. Reason: An attempt to login using SQL authentication failed. Server is configured for Windows authentication only. [CLIENT: <local machine>]
```